# How can I use !! in zsh alias

Tags: zsh, alias, command-history

I am trying to create an alias that builds upon my previous command.

Say I run

`ag foo`

After looking at the list I want to be able to use those results in vim so I do

`vim -q<(!! --vimgrep)`

The alias I want is

`alias edit-last='vim -q<(!! --vimgrep)'`

But I can't seem to use `!!` in my alias. I'm having a hard time finding info about what the `!!` is, a built-in, an alias

Comment: It must be possible with some combination of fc command

Comment: `fc -ln -1` is what you want, `!!` is history expansion and is explained in `zshexpn`. the very first page gives you the order of operations when it comes to expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!` is [history expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion). The first `!` starts a history expansion; `!!` has the [event designator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-history-event-designators) meaning the previous command.

You can access the command history via the [`fc`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc) and [`history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-history) builtins and via the [`history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-history-2) variable.

Since `--vimgrep` only makes sense with `ag`, your alias would be more useful if it applied to the last `ag` command. You can locate the previous `ag` command like this:

```
${${(M)history:#ag *}[1]}
```

Furthermore you'll need to inject the `--vimgrep` into the command.

```
alias edit-last='vim -q<(eval "${${(M)history:#ag *}[1]} --vimgrep")'
```

The last `ag` command won't make sense anymore if you've changed the current directory. This is difficult to detect. You may want to whitelist acceptable commands instead. This isn't a perfect test of course.

```
edit-last () {
  local cmd
  setopt local_options extended_glob
  for cmd in $history; do
    case $cmd in
      ((ls|(cvs|git|hg|svn) status)(| *)) :;;
      ("ag "*) vim -q<(eval "$cmd --vimgrep"); return;;
      (edit-last) :;;
      (*) echo >&2 "The previous ag command is too old."; return 125;;
    esac
  done
}
```

Comment: Absolutlely amazing! I learned more reading this sample than I did in 2 hours of googling. Thank you